# Select everything from //

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, selection

I'm making like a "mini programming language" in visual basic.
Mostly just for practice and for fun.
I just have one problem. I want to make a commenting system.
I got an idea how it would work, but i don't know how to do it.

So this is what i want to do:
I want to start to select all text from //
So for example, if i write:

```
print = "Hello World!"; //This is a comment!
```

it will select everything from the // so it will select

```
//This is a comment!
```

Then i would just replace the selected text with nothing.

Comment: Don't forget this special case:  "Hello //World!"   // Oh Oh!

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: An answer to this question won’t help you at all. Implementing a programming language requires [a **fundamental** understanding of string processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages). Once you get that understanding, the answer to your question is truly trivial. The other way around … not so much.

Comment: _I'm making like a "mini programming language" in visual basic._ How cute. Do you have any idea of the size of the can of worms you will be opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.IndexOf` + `Substring`:

```
Dim code = "Dim print = ""Hello World!""; //This is a comment!"
Dim indexOfComment = code.IndexOf("//")
Dim comment As String = Nothing
If indexOfComment >= 0 Then comment = code.Substring(indexOfComment)
```

If you want the part before the comment dont use `String.Replace` but also `Substring` or `Remove`:

```
code.Substring(0, indexOfComment)
```

Comment: That seems to work, because when i tested it by doing
_msgbox(comment)_ there came a msgbox with the comment.
But now it don't work to do: f5.replace(comment, "") to remove the comment from the result. Do you know how i could do that?

Comment: @halmi4: strings are immutable, you cannot modify them. You have to re-assign the return value from any string method to the string variable: `code = code.Replace(comment, "")`. But instead you should use the second approach i've posted(`code.Substring(0, indexOfComment)`).